# Call object method of generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a method that is passing in a object as a generic.  Note that these objects do not derive from the same class.  I have a function that I would like to call regardless of the type but am not able to call because it cannot determine the type.

```
'T' does not contain a definition for 'Validate'
```

And the code

```
public void VerifyInput<T>(T obj)
{
    ((T)obj).Validate();
}
```

This is being used to validate user data passed in.  Each of the classes are responsible for setting their own validation but they are not necessarily related in any way.
I have simplified this but the basic question remains.  How can I cast the type of a generic to call an object method?

Comment: You can't do this unless your classes derive from the same base class containing the `Validate` method or implement an interface with this method. Then you could constrain the T generic parameter to this base class or interface.

Comment: This is not possible in C# unless you specify an interface with the method `Validate` and then checks upon the generic type like "where T : IValidate` where `IValidate` is the interface with the method. Another way to do it without that is using reflection, but it's expensive.

Comment: Thanks.  I was going to add that I was aware of generic constraints but was hoping I could perform this without it.  I appreciate the update.

Comment: If you want to get wacky you could cast it to a dynamic and call Validate(), that would actually work, but be quite bad, the interface idea is much better.

Comment: See the marked duplicate for the general solution. Just declare the interface with your method, instead of a property as seen in the answer there. See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542719/call-method-on-parameter-of-generic-type and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622264/what-does-where-t-somevalue-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that these objects do not derive from the same class. I have a function that I would like to call regardless of the type but am not able to call because it cannot determine the type.

This is where you should be using an interface.

```
public interface IValidatable {
  void Validate();
}
```

And on your method

```
public void VerifyInput<T>(T obj) where T : IValidatable
{ 
  obj.Validate();
}
```

Doing this will ensure that the passed in type conforms to the interface contract but not restrict it to a specific type definition.

Answer (score 2):

Create an interface `IValidatable` with the Validate() method on there, implement it in each class and change the input of VerifyInput to take that interface and get rid of the generic types.

```
public void VerifyInput(IValidatable obj)
{
    obj.Validate();
}
```

In fact you may be able to get rid of VerifyInput completely if you do this and just call validate on the target objects.